# Jenkins not found docker when execute pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I use Jenkins with docker, but when I try to execute a build a have this problems:

> - docker pull maven:3.8.1-adoptopenjdk-11 /var/jenkins_home/workspace/project@tmp/durable-eee92a85/script.sh:
>   line 1: docker: not found

My docker-compose

```
version: "2"

services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:alpine
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    #container_name: jenkins_cdi
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    #user/senha: admin  
  
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:9000:9000"
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    environment:
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar   
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - sonarqube_bundled-plugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins

  db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=sonar
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

networks:
  sonarnet:
  #  driver: bridge

volumes:
  jenkins_home:
  driver:
  sonarqube_conf:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  sonarqube_bundled-plugins:
  postgresql:
  postgresql_data: 

  #caso de problema de memoria >> sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not installed the `docker` cli at all. You should create a new Dockerfile with jenkins as base image and install docker from there:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:alpine

RUN apk add --update docker openrc && rc-update add docker boot
```